# Getting a node stack overflow error while trying to print a dendrogram

Tags: r, dendrogram

I'm trying to get the heights of internal nodes of a `dendrogram` in a `BFS` order.

The `utils::str` function prints the `dendrogram` in a `BFS` order., so I thought I'd use that (redirect the output to a file and do some parsing on that to get the info I need).

My `'dendrogram'` has 2 branches and 5902 members total [download RDS file link: dendro.RDS](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/a4M8soZvNc).

When I try:

```
utils::str(dendro)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in getOption("OutDec") : node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
```

I tried using a simple recursion function:

```
nodeHeights <- function(dendro){
  if(is.leaf(dendro))
    0
  else{
    cat(attr(dendro,"height"),"\n")
    max(nodeHeights(dendro[[1]]),nodeHeights(dendro[[2]]))+1
  }
}
```

But:
    nodeHeights(dendro)

Throws this error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Any idea? Or any suggestion how to get the node heights of a `dendrogram` in a `BFS` order?

Comment: In my R the probkem isn't with the capture.output but rather with utils::str(dendro)

Answer (score 2):

```
> options(expressions=10000)
> nodeHeights(dendro)
[1] 1084
```

From `?options`:

> expressions   sets a limit on the number of nested expressions that will
>   be evaluated

Comment: I'm aware of that fix but it's not a stable solution - there will be a dendrogram for which this will eventually crash as well. A non-recursive O(n) is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ulimit -s <high_value>` in my .bashrc did the trick.